# Function to select hour and minutes from a string in sql Impala

Tags: sql, hadoop, impala

My table has a datetime column in the format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS". I want to split this column into separate columns for year, month, day, and time.
Currently, I am using the sql impala functions year(), month(), and day() to split the date components, but I'm having trouble getting the time in the "hh:mm" format.

I'm doing it like this:
`select  year(cast(dt_tm_entry as timestamp)), month(cast(dt_tm_entry as timestamp)), day(cast(dt_tm_entry as timestamp)), --Hour and minute from dt_tm_entry  from table`

From the documentation, I am only finding how to select hour and minutes separately using hour() and minute().

Comment: If your column is a timestamp, why do you `cast` it first?

Comment: My column is a string, so I cast it to a timestamp. I'm assuming that it's easier to extract the hour from a timestamp column than a string column, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are starting with a timestamp as a string, you could use regexp_extract to pull each component out of the string.

```
select str_timestamp
, regexp_extract(str_timestamp, '(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2}) (\\d{2}:\\d{2})', 0) as full_match
, regexp_extract(str_timestamp, '(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2}) (\\d{2}:\\d{2})', 1) as year_extract
, regexp_extract(str_timestamp, '(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2}) (\\d{2}:\\d{2})', 2) as month_extract
, regexp_extract(str_timestamp, '(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2}) (\\d{2}:\\d{2})', 3) as day_extract
, regexp_extract(str_timestamp, '(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2}) (\\d{2}:\\d{2})', 4) as time_extract
from times
```

Your other option is to extract the hours and minutes like you have been, then convert to string, lpad, and concat...

```
select concat_ws(':', lpad(cast(hour(record_created_timestamp) as string), 2, "0"), lpad(cast(minute(record_created_timestamp) as string), 2, "0"))
```